# How to change the html of div in Web Forms view with HTML passed from code behind

Tags: jquery, html, webforms

I'm working on an `ASP.NET Web Forms` project. I have vertical menu which should be presented in all the pages but I want to change to menu content depending on which page I am. I'm going to do this by fetching the data from `XML` files but for sake of simplicity right now I've hard coded the `HTML` that I want to set in one of my views like so :

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string verticalMenu = string.Empty;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           verticalMenu = @"<ul>
           <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
             </ul>
           //Some more of the same...
           </ul>";
         }
    }
 }
```

then in my view I try this:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#cssmenu').empty().html(<%= verticalMenu %>);
    });
    </script>
```

which doesn't render the desired `HTML` and I get this error in `Chrome's` console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to HTML-encode your variable before writing it out in the javascript.

If you check your generated HTML you'll see the syntax error on the js-line.

**Edit:**
Added code with the function that Leron found.

```
public partial class Default :         
    System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string verticalMenu = string.Empty;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                verticalMenu = @"<ul>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                //Some more of the same...
                </ul>";
               JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
               verticalMenu = ser.Serialize(verticalMenu);
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was searching for something like that. It turns out that if I simply use `JavaScriptSerializer` on the `HTML` string it is working fine as well but if you change you answer to actually working example I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

we can simple achieve this by giving 'runat="server"' to div and access div id in code behind 
as
     divid.innerHTML= "html code here";

if your are using "div" in master page. then we can get in other page (.cs) by

```
HtmlGenericControl h = Master.FindControl("divid") as HtmlGenericControl;
        h.InnerHtml = "dfkjsdfklj sdklflk";
```

Comment: The `div` is declared only in the `Site.Master` page and by default it seems that I don't have access to it from other pages `.CS` files. Maybe I have to add something more than just `runat="server"`?